# Two links in bootstrap nav-tabs menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6

I have the following nav-tabs.

```
<div class="my-panel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li id="343_tab" class="active">
            <a href="javascript:">[Edit]</a>
            <a href="javascript:">Tab1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It looks like this

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

When I change the li to inline-flex, it looks like two separate tabs.  No effect on any other display options.

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you're putting multiple anchors in a single list item? That's not what the Bootstrap docs recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
.nav-tabs {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs a {
  border: none !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="my-panel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="javascript:">[Edit]</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me - simple.

```
<li class="active">
   <div>
      <a href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:">Tab title</a>
   </div>
</li>
```